# Million User Fanout in Google App Engine using JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to figure out the million fanout problem for GAE using JPA.  If I understand things correctly I should have the following entities for something like Twitter (just an example):

```
public User {
    @Id Key id;
    String name;
    String displayName;
    List<Key> subscribers;  // users
}

public Tweet {
    @Id Key id;
    User tweetMaker;
    String message;
}

public TweetIndex {
    @Id Key id;
    Key tweetMaker;        // user
    List<Key> subscribers; // users
}
```

When a tweet is made, the Tweet object is saved, and a TweetIndex is saved where the tweetMaker is the user making the tweet, and the subscribers is copied from the User object into the TweetIndex.  Then I'd query on subscribers in TweetIndex to get the messages for a particular subscriber.

1. So do have that right?  Where things get fuzzy for me is I expect the subscribers to be stored into a multivalued property.  Since multivalued properties can only have 5000 entries, I think the TweetIndex should be repeated for each 5000 subscriber ids.
2. What controls breaking the multivalued properties into groups of 5000? Do I need manage the repeated saves in code?
3. And how would I store the original list of subscribers?  It seems to me that the subscriber list in the User object would also be constrained to the same 5000 limit.

Thanks for any answers/insight/suggestions!

Comment: First of all, where did you get the multi value property size limitations ? Then, just to make sure I get your use case right: can people subscribe to a Tweet of somebody they have not subscribed to ? I mean can a subscriber be in `TweetIndex` and not `User` ?

Comment: Ok I get it, multi value property size is limited when they are indexed (looks more like 20K though) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200307/what-is-maximum-size-limitation-of-listproperty-for-google-app-engine-datastore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) So do have that right? -> Kind of
Multi value property list size is limited to around 20K when indexed (which is your case, since you will run queries against subscriber IDs) [What is maximum size/limitation of ListProperty for Google App Engine datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200307/what-is-maximum-size-limitation-of-listproperty-for-google-app-engine-datastore)
To summarize it, the limitations you'll face in such a use case are :
- Indexed multi-value-property size (20K)
- Entity size (1MB) -- which should be OK unless you store blobs in there

2) The breakdown will need to be handled manually, since I don't know any persistence framework that does it.
 Objectify is the only persistence framework specialized enough with the GAE datastore to have this kind of feature, I'm not using it though so IDK.

3) You need to clearly understand the constraints that push you to model your use case on the GAE datastore.
It seems to me like you're still heavily influenced by relational database modeling :

Since you're planning for millions of users, you're building your app for scale and performance. Those "joins" are precisely what you must avoid, that's why you're not using a RDBMS in the first place.
The point is : DUPLICATE! denormalize so your data match your use cases.

```
public class UserEntity {

    @Id Key id;
    String name;

    /** INDEXED : to retrieve a user by display name */
    String displayName;

    /** For the sake of the example below */
    int tweetCount;

    /** 
     * USE CASE : See a user's followers from his "profile" page.
     *
     * Easily get subscribers data from your user entity.
     * Duplicate UserEntity (this object) 's data in the UserSubscriberEntity.
     * You just need to run an ancestor query on UserSubscriberEntity using the User id.
     */
    List<UserSubscriberChildEntity> subscribers;

}

/** Duplicate user data in this entity, retrieved easily with an ancestor query */
public class UserSubscriberChildEntity {
    /** The id of this entity */
    @Id Key subscriberId;
    /** Duplicate your User Entity data */
    String name;
    String displayName;
    /** The id from the UserEntity referenced */
    String userId;
}

public class TweetEntity {
    @Id Key id;

    /**
     * The actual text message
     */
    String tweetContent;

    /**
     * USE CASE : display the tweet maker name alongside the tweet content.
     *
     * Duplicate user data to prevent an expensive join when not needed.
     * You will always need to display this along with the tweet content !
     * Model your entity based on what you want to see when you display them
     */
    String tweetMakerName;
    String tweetMakerDisplayName;
    /**
     * USE CASE 
     * 1) to retrieve tweets MADE by a given user
     * 2) In case you actually need to access the User entity
     *    (for example, if you remove this tweet and want to decrease the user tweet counter)
     *
     * INDEXED 
     */
    Key tweetMakerId;

    /**
     * USE CASE : display tweet subscribers from the "tweet page"
     * 
     * Same as "UserSubscriberChildEntity", retrieve data fast by duplicating
     */
    List<TweetSubscriberChildEntity> subscribers;
}
```

Now the core questions : 
How do you retrieve "All the tweets one user subscribed to" ?

**Sharding your subscriptions accross entities :**

```
/**
 * USE CASE : Retrieve tweets one user subscribed to
 *
 * Same goes for User subscription
 */
public class TweetSubscriptionShardedEntity {
    /** unused */
    @Id Key shardKey;
    /** INDEXED : Tweet reference */
    Key tweetId;
    /** INDEXED : Users reference */
    List<Key> userKeys;
    /** INDEXED : subscriber count, to retrieve shards that are actually under the limitation of 20K */
    int subscribersCount = 0;

    /**
     * Add a subscriber and increment the subscriberCount
     */ 
    public void addSubscriber(Key userId) {
        userKeys.add(userId);
        subscribersCount++;
    }
}
```

**Sample tweet service that wires everything together :**

```
/**
 * Pseudo code
 */
public class TweetService {

    public List<TweetEntity> getTweetsSubscribed(Key userId) {
        List<TweetEntity> tweetsFollowed = new ArrayList<TweetEntity>;
        // Get all the subscriptions from a user
        List<TweetSubscriberShardedEntity> shards = datastoreService.find("from TweetSubscriberShardedEntity  where userKeys contains (userId)");
        // Iterate over each subscription to retrieve the complete Tweet
        for (TweetSubscriberShardedEntity shard : shards) {
            TweetEntity tweet = datastoreService.get(TweetEntity.class, shard.getTweetId);
            tweetsFollowed.add(tweet);
        }
        return tweetsFollowed;
    }

    public void subscribeToTweet(Key subscriberId, Key tweetId) {
        TweetSubscriberShardedEntity shardToUse = null;
        // Only get the first shard with under 20000 subscribers 
        TweetSubscriberShardedEntity shardNotFull = datastoreService.find("
        FROM TweetSubscriberShardedEntity  
        WHERE tweetId == tweetId 
        AND userKeys contains (subscriberId)
        AND subscribersCount < 20000 
        LIMIT 1");
        if (shardNotFull == null) {
            // If no shard exist create one
            shardToUse = new TweetSubscriberShardedEntity();
        }
        else {
            shardToUse = shardNotFull;
        }
        // Link user and tweet
        shardToUse.setTweet(tweetId);
        shardToUse.getUserKeys().add(subscriberId);
        // Save shard
        datastoreService.put(shardToUse);
    }

    /**
     * Hard to put in a transaction with so many entities updated !
     * See cross entity group docs for more info.
     */
    public void createTweet(UserEntity creator, TweetEntity newTweet) {

        creator.tweetCount++;
        newTweet.tweetMakerName = creator.name;
        newTweet.tweetMakerDisplayName = creator.displayName;
        newTweet.tweetMakerId = creator.id;

        // Duplicate User subscribers to Tweet
        for(UserSubscriberChildEntity userSubscriber : creator.subcribers) {
            // Create a Tweet child entity 
            TweetSubscriberChildEntity tweetSubscriber = new TweetSubscriberChildEntity();
            tweetSubscriber.name = userSubscriber.name;
            // ... (duplicate all data)
            newTweet.add(tweetSubscriber);

            // Create a shard with the previous method !!
            subscribeToTweet(newTweet.id, subscriber.id);
        }           
        // Update the user (tweet count)
        datastoreService.put(creator);
        // Create the new tweet and child entities (duplicated subscribers data)
        datastoreService.put(newTweet);         
    }

}
```

Comment: Note : The only reason why the `TweetSubscriptionShardedEntity` exists is because of the number of subscriptions you have. If you only had under 20K subscriptions per tweet, you could actually just have a subscribers property (`List<Key> subscribers`) directly on your tweet.