# What is maximum size/limitation of ListProperty for Google App Engine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using GAE long time but can not find what is maximum length of ListProperty.

I was read [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty) but not found solution I want to create ListProperty(long) to keep about 30 values of long or more. I want use this field as filter - can I use it similar to StringListProperty?

What is size limits of ListProperty(long)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@marcadian has a pretty good answer.  There's no limit specifically on a ListProperty.

You do need to look at datastore limits on entities though:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/#Python_Quotas_and_limits

The two most obvious limits are the 1MB maximum entity size and 20000 index entries.

Depending on what's inside your list, it may vary.  You can fit 130k 8-byte long's within that 1MB limit, but if they're indexed, you'll hit a barrier at 20k entries because of the index limit.

The worst bit is that these limits are on the total entity size, so if you have two lists in an entity, the size of one list could be limited by the what's in the other list.

Comment: That is right - entity size is limit. More danger is index entries limit but not sure if 20 000 index entries limit is working in simple way - so you can have much more entries but indexed values should 20000.

Comment: I just noticed that you said you're using this field as a filter, so you could hit the index entry limit before you hit the entity size limit.

Comment: Do you think that if I index only this field and will have more that 20 000 types of values it will break index constraint?

Comment: If you have > 20k values in this ListProperty on a given entity you'll break the index constraint.

Comment: Not understand clearly what do you mean first: I can not have 20 001 on single entity or second: 20 001 different values types in index per all entities? Better to ask then assume false thing, please explain some my doubts.

Comment: You can have as many entities in you want.  No limit.  But you cannot have a single entity with a list that contains 20001 different elements.

Comment: It is o.k. you answer is the best!

Answer (score 3):

I've a list of 20K strings (not indexed though). I don't think there is limitation on the length, but there is limitation on each entity size. Be careful on indexing multi value properties, it could be expensive.

Comment: Do you mean writes can be costly.

Comment: Well basically there is extra overhead with indexing, if not necessary, always set indexed=False

Comment: I often use indexed=False and have some tool to check in which entities I have high cost of entity write/read.

Answer (score 1):

30 will be fine.

Guido's answer about related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418435/1279005
So up to 100 repeated values will be fine.

Repeated properties much easier to understand by using NDB as I think. You should try it.
It's does not matter if you using it with Long or String properties - if the property is indexed you'll be able to filter by it.

Comment: I am not using nbd and not plan to use.